# Return full results linq grouping query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group and still retrieve all the data in the table. I'm still pretty new to Linq and can't seem to tell what I'm doing wrong. I not only want to group the results but I still want to retrieve all the columns in the table. Is this possible?

```
    (from r in db.Form
     orderby r.CreatedDate descending
     group r by r.Record into myGroup
     where myGroup.Count() > 0
     where (r.CreatedDate > lastmonth)
     where r.Name == "Test Name"
     select new { r, myGroup.Key, Count = myGroup.Count() }
    )
```

Some how "r" loses its context or since I grouped "r" it has been replaced. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split your task into two steps to accomplish what you want.

Group data

```
var groupedData = db.Form.Where(item=>item.CreatedDate > lastMonth && item.Name == "Test Name")
                    .OrderByDescending(item=>item.item.CreatedDate)
                    .GroupBy(item=>item.Record)
                    .Select(group => new {Groups = group, Key = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
                    .Where(item => item.Groups.Any());
```

From the grouped data select `Form` elements

```
var formElements = groupedData.SelectMany(g => g.Groups).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're filtering on individual records, you should filter them before grouping rather than after:

```
(
    from r in db.Form
    where r.CreatedDate > lastMonth)
    where r.Name == "Test Name"
    orderby r.CreatedDate descending
    group r by r.Record into myGroup
    where myGroup.Count() > 0
    select new { Groups = myGroup, myGroup.Key, Count = myGroup.Count() }
)
// Groups is a collection of db.Form instances
```

Comment: Gotcha, so I tried that snippet and now I get an exception. It shows the error under the "select" statement. 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Models.Form>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @JasonFoglia show what you're doing with the query.  Also, it's better to use `.Any()` rather than `.Count() > 0`.

Comment: @JasonFoglia on further reflection, I assume you're assigning the result of the query to a `List<Form>`.  That doesn't work, as you've found out.  Try this instead: `var list = (from r in db.Form ... select new { ... }).ToList();`

Comment: I'm using var list = (... The error is coming from the query itself. In the ide the red squiggle line is under the select.